# 'Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 not found in Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0

I recently upgraded my .NET projects from .NET 5.0 to .NET 6.0.

When I attempt to add a migration in Package Manager Console, I get the following error.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      6.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

I'm confused by this. Why is it looking for version 2.0.0 of *Microsoft.NETCore.App*? Is that an older version? And why would it be missing now that I've updated my projects to .NET 6.0?

I looked in my project but don't see any reference to this package. Can anyone help me understand what is wrong?

**Update**

Here is the project file for my main application.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TTRailtraxBusinessLayer\TTRailtraxBusinessLayer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TTRailtraxEntities\TTRailtraxEntities.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Attributes\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And here is the project file for the library project that contains my entities.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RailtraxCore\RailtraxCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see, there are other library projects being used as well.

Comment: It was a separate Nuget package in older versions. You may update the project SDK version but this package can still be lying in your `.csproj` file. You should delete that as newer versions don't require it.

Comment: @Eldar: Well, that's certainly useful information. But as mentioned in the question, I don't see any reference to this package.

Comment: Can you share your `csproj` file contents?

Comment: The .NET 2.0 SDK is deprecated now and Visual Studio will warn you it will remove it when you install it.

Comment: @Eldar: I added that.

Comment: @jessehouwing: But it's warning me that it can't find it. An error, in fact.

Comment: I remember seeing  warning when upgrading Visual Studio that the upgrade would uninstall the deprecated SDK from its workload. That would explain why it can't find the .NET 2 SDK now. Not why it's searching for it though.

Comment: I missed a point that this happens in `Package Manage Console` so you can build your project just fine?

Comment: @Eldar: Yes, the project builds and runs without a problem.

Comment: Check the `Default Project` in PMC it should point to a project that `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is installed.

Comment: @Eldar: Could you clarify what you mean by *check the default project*? Do you mean the main project? What do you want me to check?

Comment: Have you checked `TTRailtraxBusinessLayer`,`TTRailtraxEntities` and `RailtraxCore` to be updated to latest versions also?

Comment: @GuruStron: Yes, I checked every project in the solution.

Comment: @JonathanWood have you tried "the usual" - clean, delete bin and obj folders, reboot VS, reboot the machine?

Comment: I mean in Package Manager Console there is a section in the header `Default Project: a dropdown here` that shows the selected project.

Comment: @GuruStron: Well, the project builds and runs without error. I can try Clean but I'm confused why this would just happen with Package Manager Console.

Comment: @Eldar: Ah yes, sorry. It is set to TTRailtraxEntities because that's where my database entities are. I added the project file for this project in my question.

Comment: So what happens when you set it to the main project?

Comment: @Eldar: I get an error: *Your target project 'TTRailtrax' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'TTRailtraxEntities'*

Comment: Ok the final suggestion (only 1 left indeed). Set the default project to the project that contains your `DbContext` and set your startup project to the main application. (The one left on the play button) Multiple startup projects can mess up things. And search for a JSON file (like global.json) in your solution folder, it also has the potential to mess up things.

Comment: @Eldar: Actually, it seems to work if I set the main application as the *Startup Project*. I'm still confused why I'm getting this particular error with multiple start ups, but it appears I can now move forward. Thanks. (If you want to write an answer, I will accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Entity Framework's tooling for Powershell has a semantic to pass parameters into EF tools. It passes both the default project and the startup project but for multiple startup projects, it uses the default project as a fallback project. EF tools requires a configured DbContext (associated with a provider and connection string) this is the startup project that consumes the DbContext and configures it. And a migration assembly that locates the migrations and that is usually the project that contains DbContext. So generally when I add migrations with PMC I set the startup project to an application and set the default project in PMC to the DbContext project.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Tools/tools/EntityFrameworkCore.psm1) is the Powershell module if you want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing project framework to the ones that are found i.e 3.1 or 5.0:
Right click on project -> Properties -> Application -> Target framework
[image]

Comment: Why would I do that if I'm using the latest version of .NET?

Comment: Because project you have cloned might have set TargetFramework set to 2.0 but it was not installed on your local system. So change it to whatever you have latest on your system.

Comment: As I explained, I was upgrading my project from .NET 5.0 to .NET 6.0. I didn't clone anything. I have no interest in reverting my project back to .NET 3.1.

Comment: So then use the latest you have i.e .Net 6.0. The message :
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (x64) was not found.

Means framework 2.0 is referenced somewhere in the project but it is not found in the system. Have you checked what was the target framework set in props file?